# NUnit: Test case source cannot be found

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm getting a 'test case source cannot be found' error in the following code. I'm trying to parametrize an integration test with a bunch of example files located in the repository.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.Abstractions;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class IntegrationTestA
    {
        [TestCaseSource(nameof(InputFilesGenerator))]
        public void TestA(string inputFile)
        {
            Main(inputFile);
        }
    }

    public class InputFilesGenerator : IEnumerable
    {
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            var matcher = new Matcher();
            matcher.AddInclude("**/*.lcd");

            string workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            var rootDirectory = Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
            var searchDirectories = rootDirectory.GetDirectories("samples");

            if (searchDirectories.Length != 1) { throw new Exception("Unexpected number of samples directories"); }
            var samplesDirectory = searchDirectories[0];

            var patternMatch = matcher.Execute(new DirectoryInfoWrapper(samplesDirectory));
            foreach (var file in patternMatch.Files)
            {
                yield return file.Path.;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is modelled after the example given in the NUnit docs [here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html#form-3---testcasesourcetype-sourcetype)

I've tried `yield return new object[] { file.Path };` to no avail.

I've also tried replacing the entire enumerator code with

```
            for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                yield return i.ToString();
            }
```

which didn't help, so my issue isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this, which is using the name of the class:

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(InputFilesGenerator))]
```

It should be this, which uses the type:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(InputFilesGenerator))]
```